# Change Cocoa binding value in code

Tags: cocoa, binding

I have an `NSTextField` and it has a binding for its "value" property to "Shared User Defaults Controller", Controller Key "values", Model Key Path "myName".

Is there a way to change the value in code?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the appropriate value in the user defaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Some new name" forKey:@"myName"];
```